# why double and long double are giving different answer in the following program

Tags: c++

This code is calculating the Nth term of a series which is defined as
Tn+2=(Tn+1)^2+Tn, where 1st and 2nd terms are given as a and b in the code.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
 int a,b,n;
 char ch[100];
 cin>>a>>b>>n;
 long double res[3];
 res[0]=a,res[1]=b;
 for(int i=n-2;i>0;i--)
 {
  res[2]=res[1]*res[1]+res[0];
  res[0]=res[1];
  res[1]=res[2];
 }
 sprintf(ch,"%.0Lf",res[2]);
 cout<<ch;
 return 0;
}
```

Input: 0 1 10

Output:

```
84266613096281242861568        // in case of double res[3];

84266613096281243385856       // in case of long double res[3];

correct output : 84266613096281243382112
```

Since it is going out of the range of integer, therefore I am using double/long double.

But the problem is I am getting different output for double and long double, while none of the intermediate values are having non zero digit after decimal point, so there should not be any rounding off, I guess.

Comment: You should look into what "floating point" means.

Comment: You seem to have a fundamental misunderstanding regarding both of these data types. Did you think that both of them have unlimited integral digit places, and differ only in the number of "decimal places" they can represent? Which book are you using?

Comment: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: You are just using a different random number generator.  *double* generates up to 15 significant digits, the rest is just noise.  *long double* generates up to 19 accurate digits.  Just count them off to see that the results you got are in fact as accurate as they can be.  If you want more digits then you'll have to use a library, like Bignum.

Answer (score 1):

> while none of the intermediate values are having non zero digit after decimal point, so there should not be any rounding off, I guess.

This assumption is just plain wrong. All floating point numbers like `double` etc. are stored like

```
mantissa * 2^exponent
```

with a finite number of bits for both the mantissa and the exponent. So floating point numbers can store a fixed number of significant digits (for a `double` converted to decimal representation, around 16 usually). If a number has more digits before the decimal point, rounding will happen and the total rounding error gets bigger the more digits you need to "forget".

If you want more details on this, the most common floating point implementations follow the [IEEE floating point standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point).